# Google Glass take a note - How to display the "Noting/Noted" status card?

Tags: google-glass, status

After a user finishes speaking, I want to display a card telling the user that their data is being saved. I see that the "Take a note" Glassware does this however I can't figure out how to implement the same feature. Is the source code for "Take a note" available anywhere? If so, does anyone have a link to it?

Comment: Perhaps via EXTRA_RESULTS_PENDINGINTENT is the right way to go? Or as an AsynTask starting in onActivityResult till onResume() is reached? It doesn't seem like there are callbacks available like onEndOfSpeech() in the RecognitionListener class, which would be useful here....